# Can I claim school expenses including tuition that was paid out of pocket on my taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, school

As I stated above I am wondering if I can claim my school expenses on my taxes for this year's taxes. If it is possible how would I do so and will I get a better return because of it? I am in the United States.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: The United States